# Fragment not Opening Previous Fragment on Back Button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I have been struggling to implement a super simple app layout, where my `MainActivity` opens `Fragment#1` in its `onCreate` method, then the `Fragment#1` opens `Fragment#2` when an item is clicked.

As of right now, when I open `Fragment#1` from my `MainActivity`, I add `Fragment#1` to the BackStack. After opening `Fragment#2`, when I hit the back button the first click does nothing, then the second click sends me all the way back to my login page, skipping past `Fragment #1` and `MainActivity`.

**How can I make it so when I hit the back button on `Fragment#2`, it opens `Fragment#1` back up?**

### (`MainActivity` opens `Fragment#1`)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SearchListFragment fragment = new SearchListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(TAG);
        transaction.commit();

    }
}
```

### (`Fragment#1` opens `Fragment#2`)

```
public class SearchListFragment extends Fragment {

    public void viewResults(SearchModel search) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("ID", search.getId());
        ResultsFragment fragment = new ResultsFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I should have mentioned that I have tried to handle the back press event myself. I tried adding this to my `MainActivity` but it did not change the behavior:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            this.finish();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

onCreate with

**Kotlin**

```
   val backpress = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, true) {
                        // Handle the back button event

}
```

**Java**

```
    OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Handle the back button event
        }
    });
    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
```

You can provide your back operations in the relevant sections.

Comment: What would you suggest I put the handler? Something like `FragmentManager.popBackStack()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_frame, fragment).addToBackStack("text").commit();
```

Comment: Can you clarify? That is the almost exact code I implemented in my `onCreate` when creating `Fragment#1`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.